# How do I redirect /search/ to ?s=

Tags: redirect, wp-redirect

I have a Search page set up which uses the typical GET format

```
    <form id="searchform" action="http://example.com" method="get">
        <input id="s" type="text" name="s" placeholder="Search Again">
    </form>
```

For users' convenience, I'd like to have the following url redirect to the search page:

```
http://example.com/search?search-term
```

Redirect to:

```
http://example.com/?s=search-term
```

I also want the rewrite or redirect to handle the case of NO search parameters. That is, when the URL is simply /search or /search/ I'd still like the page to redirect to the Search template.

How do I do this?

Comment: I usually do this kind of thing with a `RewriteRule` in `.htaccess` or whatever your web server's equivalent is. It's not really specific to wordpress, so might fit better on http://serverfault.com/ or http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ (but I'm sure it has already been asked so search first).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32332624/remove-part-of-url-with-rewriterule

Comment: Has this question been resolved?

Answer (score 3):

In your `.htaccess` add the following rule in between the `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` tag:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /?s=%2 [R=301,L]
```

Based off of the default `.htaccess` generated by WordPress, it should now look like the following with your custom `RewriteRule`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
# Custom Rules
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /?s=%2 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Maybe OP is using Nginx? ;-)

Comment: Either way, I felt this question needed some closure, hopefully the OP will verify if this works since they seem relatively active.

Comment: Agree, and most likely OP is using Apache ;-)